# C++ The data type for a sentinel value is always a boolean? True or false?

Tags: c++, sentinel

just started an introductory `C++` course. I have a query as below.

The data type for a sentinel value is always a `boolean`? True or false?

Comment: It is always treated like boolean value, if you do the loop:

int n=4;

while(!n){
 n--;
}

It will be casted by compiler to the bool... also you can always see what happens by compiling your code

Comment: what " query as below"?

Comment: @Sergey: No, the words "True" and "false" in this question were not referring to the C++ keywords; it's totally inappropriate to use code markup for them.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry, i'm just tired a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at an example of a sentinel value found in the Standard:

> A null-terminated byte string, or NTBS, is a character sequence whose highest-addressed element with defined content has the value zero (the terminating null character); no other element in the sequence has the value zero.

But what type is this character sequence (and the value zero that ends it)?

> A *character sequence* is an array object `A` that can be declared as `T A [N]`, where `T` is any of the types `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, optionally qualified by any combination of `const` or `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel value need not necessarily be a boolean type, it depends on your program logic to determine what should be a best sentinel value/data type.

See some examples here:-

http://www.mikeware.us/cpp/?p=20.

Answer (score 0):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

> Below are some examples of common sentinel values and their uses:
>
> - Null character for indicating the end of a null-terminated string
> - Null pointer for indicating the end of a linked list
> - A negative integer for indicating the end of a sequence of non-negative integers
> - End-of-file, a non-character value returned by certain input routines to signal that no further characters are available from a
>     file
> - High Values, a key value of hexadecimal 0xFF used in business programming

So it all depends how you define "sentinel"